# What does this expression mean?

Tags: math

I'm writing a small application about image retrieval, but I can't understand what this mathematical expression means

d^2 = || x - p ||^2
where x and p are two-element vectors.

Can somebody tell me what means this ||, and how can I raise a vector to power ??

EDIT
Thanks to espertus answer I know that  || x - p ||^2 is a euclidean distance. However I also came across this expression ||p||^2 . What would that mean ? I think that it can't be euclidean distance. What else could it be ?

Comment: || x - p ||^2 is *not* the distance between x and p. It is the *square* of this distance. For instance, if x = (1, 3) and p = (5, 6) then x - p = (-4, -3) and || x - p || = sqrt( (-4)^2 + (-3)^2 ) = 5. Hence, the distance between x and p is 5 units of length. || x - p ||^2 = 25 is the square of the distance.

Answer (score 5):

The two bars refer to the length of a vector, which is the square root of the sum of the squares of the coordinates.  See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_vector#Length.

Comment: Thanks for answer but what would mean ||p||^2 - p is a two element vector ?? I also found this kind expression in papaer I'm currently reading

Comment: @john: x and p are vectors, and so is their difference x - p. For any vector v, the symbol || v || denotes the length (or norm) of the vector, which is (most often) the square root of the sum of the squares of the vector's components. Thus || x - p || is the length of the difference vector x - p, or, in other words, the *distance* between the points x and p in the plane. Similarily, || p || is the length of the vector p, or || p - 0 ||, the distance between the origin and the vector. Since || v || is a real number for any vector v, it makes sense to square it, and so || v ||^2 is this square.

Answer (score 0):

"EDIT Thanks to espertus answer I know that || x - p ||^2 is a euclidean distance. However I also came across this expression ||p||^2 . What would that mean ? I think that it can't be euclidean distance. What else could it be ?"

It would be the magnitude of the vector p.  If p is expressed in terms of its terminus coordinates (x, y) or (x, y, z), then ||p|| is the distance from the origin (0, 0) or (0, 0, 0) to the terminus.